# How would I go about creating an advanced calculator?

Tags: java

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask this. I am a beginner programmer, and I just managed to make this simple calculator that can calculate addition, subtraction, multiplication and division:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){

            System.out.println("Format a 'tegn' b");
            System.out.println("tegn: +,-,*,/?");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            double a = input.nextDouble();
            String valgttegn;
            valgttegn = input.next();
            double b = input.nextDouble();

            if (valgttegn.equals("+")) {
                System.out.println("Resultat = " + (a + b));
            } else if (valgttegn.equals("-")) {
                System.out.println("Resultat = " + (a - b));
            } else if (valgttegn.equals("*")) {
                System.out.println("Resultat = " + (a * b));
            } else if (valgttegn.equals("/")) {
                System.out.println("Resultat = " + (a / b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what I should begin to research, so that I would be able to expand the functionality of the calculator to provide more advanced functions, like the square root of a number.

Comment: It would all depend on how you wanted to evolve the calculator. Do you want to have multiple memories to be able to recall? It's always handy to get to grips with the Java collections - know difference between arrays, lists, maps, sets (tuples for other languages). That will stand you in good stead for any programming language.  Also try and get your head around generics.

Comment: **Research:** [`expression parsing`](https://www.google.com/search?q=expression+parsing) --- Logical (right?), given that something like `5 + (7 * 9)` is called an *expression* and that you'd need to *parse* it before you can *evaluate* it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to implement more advanced functions by hand (for istance, because you want to practice), you could search for the algorithms in the web and implement them yourself. For example, [here](https://medium.com/@surajregmi/how-to-calculate-the-square-root-of-a-number-newton-raphson-method-f8007714f64) there is the first result I retrievied googling for algorithms for calculating the square root of a number .

Otherwise, there is a [java library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) for this.

If you feel confident in your object-oriented skills and you are interested into how to expand the functionalities of your progam in a easy and maintainable way, I suggest you to learn about [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).